# How to sum two lists items in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'A': [-1,-1,-1], 'B': [-1,-1,-1], 'C': [0,0,1]}
my_list=['A','C']
```

I want to find the average for 'A' and 'C' such that the average is a new list that contains the values for the dictionary keys A and C divided by 2:

```
result=[(-1+0)/2, (-1+0)/2, (-1+1)/2]
```

i.e, `result=[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0]`

How can I compute the result ? Note that `my_list=['A','C']` is not fixed, so please do not use fixed values.

EDIT: `my_list=['A','C']` is a variable passed to a function. It could be for example ['A','B','C']. So please, consider this. I can not use 'A' and 'C' explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you really want to be using pandas, or at least numpy. In pandas this is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-1,-1,-1], 'B': [-1,-1,-1], 'C': [0,0,1]})
my_list = ['A', 'C']
data[my_list].mean(axis=1)
```

In any case, in normal python this is:

```
[sum(values)/float(len(my_list)) for values in zip(*[my_dict[key] for key in my_list])]
```

Comment: Should be: `[(float(a)+c)/2 for a,c in zip(my_dict['A'],my_dict['C'])]`

Comment: I cheated and used `2.` to make the answer a float. Edited to `2.0` to make it clear.

Comment: @U2EF1: kindly, check the post edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
from __future__ import division # for python < 3 only
my_dict = {'A': [-1,-1,-1], 'B': [-1,-1,-1], 'C': [0,0,1]}
my_list=['A','C']
l = []
for v in zip(*(my_dict[x] for x in my_list)):
    l += [ sum(v) / len(v) ]
```

If you have Python 2.x then you need the future.division for float division. The above should work for any number of items in `my_list`. For example, for `my_list = ['A,' B', 'C']`, it yields:

```
[-0.666, -0.666, -0.333]
```

Comment: `(va + vc) / float(len(my_list))`, instead of just 2. Possibly better to avoid the division issue entirely.